# Playing sound while displaying a splash screen?

Tags: c#, audio, splash-screen

I want to play a sound while my splash screen gets data from the server.

The sound file is not too large. I want something like when you start your computer you hear the MSWinXP welcome sound and that while establishing your account.

How can I do that?

thnx

Comment: Please make sure this is configurable (ie. you can turn it off - preferrably, leave it off and allow people to turn it on). Unless this is a game, it will annoy a lot of users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`System.Media.SoundPlayer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.media.soundplayer.aspx). You may need to put this code in Form_Load instead.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Media.SoundPlayer player = new System.Media.SoundPlayer();
        player.SoundLocation = @"C:\Windows\Media\chimes.wav";
        player.Play();
    }
```